# ¿Como subir imagen al servidor local de manera externa?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un problema al intentar subir una foto a mi servidor local, todo funciona bien si uso un *action* y hago referencia la carpeta donde esta mi archivo php, pero no es lo que necesito porque me redirecciona a una pagina vacía, necesito que me redireccione a otro html fuera del servidor y guarde la imagen dentro de mi carpeta en el disco local, no se si mi archivo JS este mal porque al parecer no logra ejecutar.

PHP

```
<?php 
$tmp_name = $_FILES['img_up']["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES['img_up']["name"];
$nuevo_path="apkw/img/".$name;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$nuevo_path);
?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    read(0);

});

var host = "http://localhost:8080"; 

function read() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: host + "/subir.php"

    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#nel").empty();
        if (data.length > 0) {
            var html = "";

            $.each(data, function(i) {
                console.log(data[i]);
                html += '';
            })
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="img_up">
            <input value="Subir" type="submit" >
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prueba.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Disculpa no se entiende bien tu pregunta, lo que intentas decir es usar tu servidor como pasarela al momento de subir una imagen y que esta se guarde en otro servidor diferente (digamos AWS)

Comment: De momento estoy trabajando de forma local, quiero que la imagen se guarde en mi carpeta htdocs en mi disco local, no intento que solo sea como pasarela, sino que ahí se quede. Tratare de formular mejor mi pregunta

Comment: revisa primero si la imagen efectivamente se esta subiendo a htdocs, si es asi, solo tienes un problema de permisos de escritura, el usuario que corre php no tiene permisos de escritura sobre la carpeta en que quieres almacenar los archivos.

Comment: ¿Porqué llamas a read con parámetro 0 pero no lo regojes en la función? ¿eso no da error? ¿has mirado la consola de errores de javascript? ¿has mirado el error.log de apache o servidor web?

Comment: @RicardoD.Quiroga Se sube sin problema si ocupo en el HTML action="http://localhost:8080/subir.php" pero se sube la imagen y me redirecciona a una pagina vacía debido al action, quiero tener otra alternativa para que se logre la subida de la foto sin ocupar el action

Comment: @track3r tenia la idea que de esta manera leeria el archivo **subir.php** que tengo en el servidor, pero creo que estoy en lo erroneo

Comment: Te lo comento porque si hay un error de javascript, el proceso nunca se completará, en otras palabras, la llamada ajax no llegará a ejecutarse. Ya nos dirás el resultado de quitar el 0, pero mejor mira los errores generados en la consola del inspector de javascript.

Comment: Bueno, de todas formas hay más trabajo ahí, la función ajax que usas no está completa ni preparada para enviar un fichero. Primero debes recoger la variable "file" del input y añadir varios parámetros más... mejor te pongo una simple respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Te copio parte de la solución por parte de Raphael Schweikert en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Primero guardas los valores del form:

```
var fdata = new FormData();
$.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    fdata.append('file-'+i, file);
});
```

Como llamamos al input por su id, tendrás que añadirlo:

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="img_up">
```

Luego llamas con ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: host + "/subir.php",
    data: fdata,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    method: 'POST',
    type: 'POST',
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#nel").empty();
    if (data.length > 0) {
        var html = "";
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            console.log(data[i]);
            html += '';
        });
    }
});
```

En la parte de PHP, verás el fichero en la variable:

```
$_FILES['file-0']
```

Más o menos así:

```
<?php
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file-0']["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES['file-0']["name"];
    $nuevo_path="apkw/img/".$name;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$nuevo_path);
?>
```

Otra alternativa sería usar header para cambiar de ubicación en la pantalla que se te queda en blanco:

```
header("Location: index.html");
```

En este último caso se añadiría luego de move_uploaded_file... y te saltarías toda la parte de postear el fichero por ajax.

Comment: Salvo el hecho de que la asignación de nombre no es segura `$name = $_FILES['file-0']["name"]; $nuevo_path="apkw/img/".$name;` y crea agujeros de seguridad en el sistema de archivos, esta respuesta es excelente y debiera recogerse en un tópico similar a ¿Cómo subir archivos usando ajax?